# Best practices about database relation and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Assume that a `User` can ask for a `Service` and many `Providers` can make an `Offer`. The `User` will then choose one `Offer` and make a `Transaction` for it.

Here are the tables:

```
User:
-id
-name
-address

Service:
-id
-userId
-name
-description

Provider:
-id
-name
-url

Offer:
-id
-serviceId
-providerId
-price
-details
-transactionId

Transaction:
-id
-date
-status (completed, pending etc)
-method (paypal, direct credit card etc)
```

Ok all the tables have links and we can join to find anything. But my question is: Does it makes sense to store the buyerId (user) and the sellerId(provider) in the transaction even though I can join the tables to get the buyerId and sellerId?

Comment: By which fields will you join Provider and User if Transaction doesn't contain their ID?

Comment: user is linked to service, provider is linked to offer, service is linked to offer, and offer to transaction

Comment: I don't think it makes sense a Service has a UserId - a Service can exists without being related to any User. The relation between Offer and Transaction seems backward: If there is no Transaction, the `transactionId` on Offer will be NULL.

Comment: Since several users are stored in the table, I'd call it `users` instead of user. (And `services`, `providers` etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it doesnt make sense. If you have a way to make a join and obtain the results, you should never put this additional columns on the table. Because it will be redundant, and may be can cause errors.

If you need great performance in queries that involve Transaction Table, just make good indexes, but (almost) never add unnecesary columns.

Read more here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization

Comment: ok, i just wanted to confirm that.. i never add redundant columns but sometimes i just think that making joins is costly when you will use the relation over and over again.

Comment: It has a cost, but if you dont have SUPER big tables, is not neccesary to add redundant information. 
If you have performance problems, redundance is a tool you can consider.... but first you can try a lot of different things

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a different schema:

```
User (id, name, address)

Service (id, name, description)

Provider (id, name, url)

Offer (id, userId, serviceId, providerId, price, details)

Transaction (id, offerId, date, status, method)
```

The Offer will bring together User, Service and Provider and a Transaction is a follow-up to an Offer.

Consider that a User will pick from multiple Offers, creating a Transaction only for one Offer.
Also one Provider may propose multiple Offers for the same Service to the same User each time with a reduced price.

Comment: i agree with you, but the `Service` is created by the `User`. Every user can request different kind of `Service` so i think it makes sense that `userId` is in `Service`.

Comment: And also, the system will expand later offering other things... consider `Service` as `Service1` and `Offer` as `Service1_Offer` and later `Service2` and `Service2_Offer` with all using the same `Transaction` table. So i think it's better that the `transactionId` is stored in the `Offer` table. right?

Comment: No, offerId has to go to the Transaction table - otherwise you would need to create an Transaction before you could create a valid Offer. Offer must not know about Transaction because it may never be related to one.

Comment: Concerning Service having a `userId` really depends on your definition of Service. Is your Service really tied to one User, i.e. a one-to-one relation? Especially since Provider will deliver the Service (as I understand your business case).

Comment: Correction: The relation User-Service is of course one-to-many in your solution (not one-to-one as I stated i my previous comment).